# How can I show the Lowest Price from a specific Country only?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

**Question Background:**

I am using the ProductAdvertising API to pull back details based on `Keywords` and a `SearchIndex`.

The following are the `Response Groups` I'm using:

```
    r1["Service"] = "AWSECommerceService";
    r1["ItemPage"] = 1;
    r1["ResponseGroup"] = "Large,Offers";
    r1["AssociateTag"] = "compar0c2-21";
    r1["Operation"] = "ItemSearch";
    r1["Condition"] = "New";
    r1["Availability"] = "Available";
    r1["SearchIndex"] = "ProductToSearchFor"
    r1["Keywords"] = "ItemCatagory"
```

**The Issue:**

This is giving me the data I want but the lowest price can be from sellers from all over the world. **I want the lowest prices from the UK only how can I do this?** The following Screenshot should show what I mean:

[image]

The lowest price is from New York which is not what I want, the other prices shown are from New York and Japan I want UK sellers only.

This is an example of my response I am receiving of an `<Item>` element in the XML

```xml
<Item>
  <ASIN>B0072C8SMQ</ASIN> 
  <DetailPageURL>http://www.amazon.co.uk/Omega-Seamaster-Diver-Co-Axial-212-30-41-20-01-003/dp/B0072C8SMQ%3FSubscriptionId

%3DAKIAIFERUZJXWJ3Y2USA%26tag%3Dcompar0c2-21%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN

%3DB0072C8SMQ</DetailPageURL> 
<ItemLinks>
<ItemLink>
  <Description>Add To Wishlist</Description> 
  <URL>http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/registry/wishlist/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3DB0072C8SMQ%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAIFERUZJXWJ3Y2USA

%26tag%3Dcompar0c2-21%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D12734%26creativeASIN%3DB0072C8SMQ</URL> 
  </ItemLink>
<ItemLink>
  <Description>Tell A Friend</Description> 
  <URL>http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/pdp/taf/B0072C8SMQ%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIFERUZJXWJ3Y2USA%26tag%3Dcompar0c2-21%26linkCode

%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D12734%26creativeASIN%3DB0072C8SMQ</URL> 
  </ItemLink>
<ItemLink>
  <Description>All Customer Reviews</Description> 
  <URL>http://www.amazon.co.uk/review/product/B0072C8SMQ%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIFERUZJXWJ3Y2USA%26tag%3Dcompar0c2-21%26linkCode

%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D12734%26creativeASIN%3DB0072C8SMQ</URL> 
  </ItemLink>
<ItemLink>
  <Description>All Offers</Description> 
  <URL>http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/offer-listing/B0072C8SMQ%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIFERUZJXWJ3Y2USA%26tag%3Dcompar0c2-21%26linkCode

%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D12734%26creativeASIN%3DB0072C8SMQ</URL> 
  </ItemLink>
  </ItemLinks>
  <SalesRank>30472</SalesRank> 
<SmallImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51dpiEHcAoL._SL75_.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">75</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">46</Width> 
  </SmallImage>
<MediumImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51dpiEHcAoL._SL160_.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">160</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">97</Width> 
  </MediumImage>
<LargeImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51dpiEHcAoL.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">500</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">304</Width> 
  </LargeImage>
<ImageSets>
<ImageSet Category="variant">
<SwatchImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31fExLiRjVL._SL30_.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">10</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">30</Width> 
  </SwatchImage>
<SmallImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31fExLiRjVL._SL75_.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">25</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">75</Width> 
  </SmallImage>
<ThumbnailImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31fExLiRjVL._SL75_.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">25</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">75</Width> 
  </ThumbnailImage>
<TinyImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31fExLiRjVL._SL110_.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">36</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">110</Width> 
  </TinyImage>
<MediumImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31fExLiRjVL._SL160_.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">52</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">160</Width> 
  </MediumImage>
<LargeImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31fExLiRjVL.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">164</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">500</Width> 
  </LargeImage>
  </ImageSet>
<ImageSet Category="variant">
<SwatchImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41FfUhyWQUL._SL30_.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">30</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">24</Width> 
  </SwatchImage>
<SmallImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41FfUhyWQUL._SL75_.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">75</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">60</Width> 
  </SmallImage>
<ThumbnailImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41FfUhyWQUL._SL75_.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">75</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">60</Width> 
  </ThumbnailImage>
<TinyImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41FfUhyWQUL._SL110_.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">110</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">88</Width> 
  </TinyImage>
<MediumImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41FfUhyWQUL._SL160_.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">160</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">128</Width> 
  </MediumImage>
<LargeImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41FfUhyWQUL.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">500</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">401</Width> 
  </LargeImage>
  </ImageSet>
<ImageSet Category="variant">
<SwatchImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31MpUA8mLjL._SL30_.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">15</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">30</Width> 
  </SwatchImage>
<SmallImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31MpUA8mLjL._SL75_.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">38</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">75</Width> 
  </SmallImage>
<ThumbnailImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31MpUA8mLjL._SL75_.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">38</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">75</Width> 
  </ThumbnailImage>
<TinyImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31MpUA8mLjL._SL110_.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">55</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">110</Width> 
  </TinyImage>
<MediumImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31MpUA8mLjL._SL160_.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">80</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">160</Width> 
  </MediumImage>
<LargeImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31MpUA8mLjL.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">250</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">500</Width> 
  </LargeImage>
  </ImageSet>
<ImageSet Category="primary">
<SwatchImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51dpiEHcAoL._SL30_.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">30</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">18</Width> 
  </SwatchImage>
<SmallImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51dpiEHcAoL._SL75_.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">75</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">46</Width> 
  </SmallImage>
<ThumbnailImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51dpiEHcAoL._SL75_.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">75</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">46</Width> 
  </ThumbnailImage>
<TinyImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51dpiEHcAoL._SL110_.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">110</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">67</Width> 
  </TinyImage>
<MediumImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51dpiEHcAoL._SL160_.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">160</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">97</Width> 
  </MediumImage>
<LargeImage>
  <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51dpiEHcAoL.jpg</URL> 
  <Height Units="pixels">500</Height> 
  <Width Units="pixels">304</Width> 
  </LargeImage>
  </ImageSet>
  </ImageSets>
<ItemAttributes>
  <Binding>Watch</Binding> 
  <Brand>Omega</Brand> 
<CatalogNumberList>
  <CatalogNumberListElement>212.30.41.20.01.003</CatalogNumberListElement> 
  </CatalogNumberList>
  <EAN>0640522174386</EAN> 
<EANList>
  <EANListElement>0640522174386</EANListElement> 
  </EANList>
<ItemDimensions>
  <Weight Units="hundredths-pounds">39</Weight> 
  </ItemDimensions>
  <Label>Omega</Label> 
  <Manufacturer>Omega</Manufacturer> 
  <Model>212.30.41.20.01.003</Model> 
  <MPN>212.30.41.20.01.003</MPN> 
<PackageDimensions>
  <Height Units="hundredths-inches">440</Height> 
  <Length Units="hundredths-inches">670</Length> 
  <Weight Units="hundredths-pounds">255</Weight> 
  <Width Units="hundredths-inches">660</Width> 
  </PackageDimensions>
  <PackageQuantity>1</PackageQuantity> 
  <PartNumber>212.30.41.20.01.003</PartNumber> 
  <ProductGroup>Watch</ProductGroup> 
  <ProductTypeName>WATCH</ProductTypeName> 
  <Publisher>Omega</Publisher> 
  <Studio>Omega</Studio> 
  <Title>Omega Seamaster Diver 300 m Co-Axial 212.30.41.20.01.003</Title> 
  <UPC>640522174386</UPC> 
<UPCList>
  <UPCListElement>640522174386</UPCListElement> 
  </UPCList>
  </ItemAttributes>
<OfferSummary>
<LowestNewPrice>
  <Amount>247980</Amount> 
  <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode> 
  <FormattedPrice>£2,479.80</FormattedPrice> 
  </LowestNewPrice>
  <TotalNew>6</TotalNew> 
  <TotalUsed>0</TotalUsed> 
  <TotalCollectible>0</TotalCollectible> 
  <TotalRefurbished>0</TotalRefurbished> 
  </OfferSummary>
<Offers>
  <TotalOffers>1</TotalOffers> 
  <TotalOfferPages>1</TotalOfferPages> 
  <MoreOffersUrl>http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/offer-listing/B0072C8SMQ%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIFERUZJXWJ3Y2USA%26tag%3Dcompar0c2-

21%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D12734%26creativeASIN%3DB0072C8SMQ</MoreOffersUrl> 
<Offer>
<OfferAttributes>
  <Condition>New</Condition> 
  </OfferAttributes>
<OfferListing>
  <OfferListingId>xEcyAMJL84cxvF%2BBjncJMoZfAR0GvbqG1LLRal0iDmyldGMHib9EBz0%2BVYWa6Mb1N

%2FIgW3EVvVYPE78iuB0q7QGCie2J5oFSn5UszusOe1rd29OZiUE6%2FWsaXL7vkuqmQrWO7gTTn5E154Kw85dz5FOF0R1NoD0M</OfferListingId> 
<Price>
  <Amount>247980</Amount> 
  <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode> 
  <FormattedPrice>£2,479.80</FormattedPrice> 
  </Price>
  <Availability>Usually dispatched within 1-2 business days</Availability> 
<AvailabilityAttributes>
  <AvailabilityType>now</AvailabilityType> 
  <MinimumHours>24</MinimumHours> 
  <MaximumHours>48</MaximumHours> 
  </AvailabilityAttributes>
  <IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping>0</IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping> 
  <IsEligibleForPrime>0</IsEligibleForPrime> 
  </OfferListing>
  </Offer>
  </Offers>
<CustomerReviews>
  <IFrameURL>http://www.amazon.co.uk/reviews/iframe?akid=AKIAIFERUZJXWJ3Y2USA&alinkCode=xm2&asin=B0072C8SMQ&atag=compar0c2-

21&exp=2015-11-11T22%3A11%3A40Z&v=2&sig=XtADbxHdEnxWODWBtgqIaxyMvxyJof03t9HjDHxSMm4%3D</IFrameURL> 
  <HasReviews>true</HasReviews> 
  </CustomerReviews>
<EditorialReviews>
<EditorialReview>
  <Source>Product Description</Source> 
  <Content>Omega Seamaster Diver 300 m Co-Axial no Product Detail</Content> 
  <IsLinkSuppressed>0</IsLinkSuppressed> 
  </EditorialReview>
  </EditorialReviews>
<BrowseNodes>
<BrowseNode>
  <BrowseNodeId>199483031</BrowseNodeId> 
  <Name>Luxury Watches</Name> 
<Ancestors>
<BrowseNode>
  <BrowseNodeId>328229011</BrowseNodeId> 
  <Name>Categories</Name> 
  <IsCategoryRoot>1</IsCategoryRoot> 
<Ancestors>
<BrowseNode>
  <BrowseNodeId>328228011</BrowseNodeId> 
  <Name>Watches</Name> 
  </BrowseNode>
  </Ancestors>
  </BrowseNode>
  </Ancestors>
  </BrowseNode>
<BrowseNode>
  <BrowseNodeId>246334031</BrowseNodeId> 
  <Name>Watches Outlet</Name> 
<Ancestors>
<BrowseNode>
  <BrowseNodeId>401431011</BrowseNodeId> 
  <Name>Regular Stores</Name> 
<Ancestors>
<BrowseNode>
  <BrowseNodeId>328232011</BrowseNodeId> 
  <Name>Substores</Name> 
<Ancestors>
<BrowseNode>
  <BrowseNodeId>328228011</BrowseNodeId> 
  <Name>Watches</Name> 
  </BrowseNode>
  </Ancestors>
  </BrowseNode>
  </Ancestors>
  </BrowseNode>
  </Ancestors>
  </BrowseNode>
  </BrowseNodes>
  </Item>
<Item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Further investigation I don't believe what I want is actually possible. I could potentially work out the country of origin from the Shipping details but these are sparse. For now on I'll just accept that the lowest seller may come from abroad rather than the UK only.

Answer (score 1):

```
<LowestNewPrice>
  <Amount>247980</Amount> 
  <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode> 
  <FormattedPrice>£2,479.80</FormattedPrice> 
</LowestNewPrice>
```

It's already showing you lowest price.

Comment: Correct, BUT I only want the prices from the UK. As you can see in my image the lowest prices come from Japan and New York. After further investigation I dont believe it is actually possible to achieve what I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

Attach your request details so we can have an advance look at your problem. As being said above, you already have the lowest price.

Comment: After further investigation I dont believe it is actually possible to achieve what I'm after